# Excel: How do I declare variables in one cell, and define them in another?

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

Is it possible to declare variables in a formula in one cell, and then define the variables in another cell, where also the result of the formulr from the first cell has to be presented.

EXAMPLE:
Formula in cell A1:
(=x+y).
Result in cell A2:
The result of the A1 formula has to be shown in A2.
The definitions of the two A1 formula variables, f.ex. "X=5" and "Y=3", has to be placed in A2 too.
RESULT:
A2: "=Result of A1, providing x=3 and y=5"

On the screen it would look something like this:
(A1 = ?????) and
(A2 = 8)

Answer (score 2):

You can **define a formula for one cell (A2) by writing it as a text in another cell (A1**) by using VBA. The basic idea is this:

```
Range("A2").Formula = "=" & Range("A1").Value
```

Keep in mind not to write "=" in front of the Formula in A1, or the formula will be evaluated there. The trick is that the formula will be treated like normal text when doing so. Therefore the "=" has to be put in front of the formula when assigning it from the text in A1.

**[EDIT1] I got your question wrong. Here's another try:**

To be able to use "variables" you provide in the SAME cell as the result, you would have to:

- Extract the "variables" from the text in A2 (e.g. RegEx)
- Replace the variable-names in A1 with the values of the variables found in A2 and store that in a temporary string variable (formula_string)
- Evaluate the formula and set the value/text of A2 according to your pattern

  Range("A2").Value = "Result: " & Evaluate(formula_string) & " using & Range("A2").Value

I have no excel here to try it out, but I think you get what I mean.

**[EDIT2] Another try, according to your comment:**

You can save yourself a lot of hassle if you use the following approach:

Let's say you have the years vertically (from top to bottom) and the months horizontally (from left to right)

- Write the year "numbers" left of the matrix
- Write the month "numbers" above the matrix
- Now you can write the formula in one cell and just "drag" it along to the other cells,
  you just have to "fixate" the row for the month and the column for the year (You can do that by writing a $-Sign in front of the dimension you want to fixate

I hope that is what you wanted.

Comment: @Bellman: Just one question: Why do you want to do something that complicated? ;)

Comment: Thanks, but I don’t know VB. I build a calendar-matrix (years horiz., months vert.) for budget overview. In each cell (15yrs x 12mth = 180) I place a formula, that checks for expenses (placed outside matrix), and calculates monthly savings needed.
The formula is big, and I want to avoid ‘identical’ formulas in all cells (they only differ with year (2011-25) and month (1-12).  I want to place the formula once outside the matrix. From each cell (eg. A1 = year: "2011" / jan month:  "1") I will CALL the big formula, REPLACE the variables with "2011" and "1", and show RESULT - all in SAME cell.